# How mechanical HDD's determine which files to overwrite when copying data

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems

Hard drive size: 100GB and it did contain a bunch of files of varying megabytes file sizes which all got added at different times and accumilated over time... they all got deleted...

I then copied 25GB of data (small files mbs in size) onto the empty drive...

Which deleted files get overwritten first? the ones added last or the ones added first?  Or does the drive spread all the files in a scattering motion all over random places within the 100GB space.

So, is it random deleted files that get overwritten regardless of date added, or do the earliest added deleted files get overwritten first?

Comment: The drive has no idea what a file is, what space is used, what space is free, or anything like that. It has no control over the read and write requests it receives.

Answer (score 2):

Hard disks, either HDDs or SSDs, don't understand the concept of files at all. They only store a sequence of bytes and that's all they care about. <sup>[1]</sup>

Hard disks are usually partitioned and partitions are formatted with a file system of choice (FS). <sup>[2]</sup> The file system that decides how and where files are stored.

The answer to your question is: **it depends**.

File system doesn't really care when a file was created or deleted. Once it's deleted, it doesn't exist anymore, file system will treat it just as garbage bytes, not as a file.

What's more, files aren't stored continuously: a single file may get split into multiple chunks and scattered all over the partition. It's file system's job to reassemble it on the fly so that OS doesn't realize it was sliced in the first place. Counter-intuitively, it may actually improve performance: controlled fragmentation can be used to facilitate the fact that outer parts of HDD platters offer better read/write speeds and to avoid situations where FS is forced to fragment a file in a sub-optimal way because it can't fit it in any desirable part of disk.

Writing patterns for specific file systems may be predictable for specific cases, but not in general. Sizes of specific files and the order in which you store them will affect it. When storing a new file, file system won't consider whether the space it's going to use was used or not; it won't prefer previously-used addresses over "clean" ones or the other way around. Once a file is deleted, FS treats the space it occupied identically as space that was never used.

---

[1] Modern drives have additional layer of abstraction, so the regions actually used for storage of these bytes may not be sequential or contiguous (for example because of bad block remapping in HDDs and wear leveling in SSDs). That doesn't matter for the scope of the question though, let's just say that all hard disks expose themselves to other hardware and OS as a device that can store a number of reliably addressed sequential bytes.

[2] Modern Windows versions use NTFS on OS partitions and NTFS or FAT32 on additional ones. Flash disks typically use FAT32 or sometimes exFAT. Linux usually lives in ext4 file system. Apple was using HFS+ and is now migrating to APFS. There are also some file systems for special use cases, for example scalability-oriented Btrfs and ZFS which was designed as an all-in-one fail-safe data storage solution.

Comment: "The answer to your question is: -> it depends. " Like +1

Answer (score 1):

While it is not truly random in a situation like this it is for all practical purposes random.  Note, however, that even if the directories have been overwritten sometimes the files can be found by programs that search the whole disk.  While I have done such things by eyeball in the era of floppy disks these days it is only feasible if the file has some sort of signature.